# Rewriting old React syntax to new one

Tags: reactjs

In the [react date-time](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime) documentation. It has this snippet to create my own date time component. As this createClass method is deprecated, I wish to rewrite into the new syntax using the Class Component. I am struggling with one bit which is what to do with the clear() function. Below is the documentation code with old syntax.

```
var MyDTPicker = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return <Datetime renderInput={ this.renderInput } />;
    },
    renderInput: function( props, openCalendar, closeCalendar ){
        function clear(){
            props.onChange({target: {value: ''}});
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...props} />
                <button onClick={openCalendar}>open calendar</button>
                <button onClick={closeCalendar}>close calendar</button>
                <button onClick={clear}>clear</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

My attempt with new syntax

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Datetime from 'react-datetime';

class MyDateTimePicker extends React.Component {

    renderInput(props, openCalendar, closeCalendar) {
        return (
            <div>
                <input {...props} />
                <button onClick={openCalendar}>open calendar</button>
                <button onClick={closeCalendar}>close calendar</button>
                <button onClick={}>clear</button>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return <Datetime renderInput={this.renderInput} />;
    }
}

export default MyDateTimePicker;
```

As you can see, I am not sure what to do with the clear function

----Update----

I am getting an error attempting the answer below

[image: Attempt]

-----Update---

After trying the update. I get the following console error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.clear is not a function

I think it is because it should be

> onClick={this.clear}

When I do this it renders fine with the clear button. However it does not do anything. I think it is because the props inside the clear function is now outsude of rendeInput's contex which does nothing?

Comment: Are you using the Babel plugin for class properties? https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties

Comment: I dont think so. Should I though? If it is optional, what would be the correct syntax

Comment: A method declaration without the arrow syntax like the one you have for renderInput will work without the plugin

Comment: Just keep clear as an inner function in renderInput as in the old syntax, the new syntax doesn't interfere